# BLE Button Disconnecting after ~30 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm implementing a simple connection to a blue tooth low energy push-to-talk button. Everything works well, except the fact that the device (iphone) disconnects from the peripheral after ~30 seconds.

I'm using a singleton to manage the `CBCentralManager` and hold a strong ref to the `CBPeripheral`, and after reading all of the other StackOverflow questions/answers, I couldn't find anything concise.

Here is the code:

```
//DeviceManager.m

-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(nullable NSError *)error{
    NSArray *services = peripheral.services;
    for(CBService *service in services){
        if([service.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:(NSString*)UUID_SERVICE_BUTTON]){
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
        }
    }
}
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverIncludedServicesForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error{

}
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"START DATE %@",[NSDate new]);
    NSArray <CBCharacteristic*> * characteristics = service.characteristics;
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in characteristics) {
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        if([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:(NSString*)UUID_SERVICE_BUTTON_CHARATERISTIC_STATE]){
        }
        [peripheral discoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverDescriptorsForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@",characteristic);
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
}
```

** Keep in mind the BT device has only 1 service, 1 characteristic, and 1 descriptor **

What am I missing here??

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling `connect()` on your manager? Are delegate's methods 
 `didConnect` and `didDisconnectPeripheral` called? What error does `didDisconnectPeripheral` return?

Comment: Are you allowed to be connected that long? Some device can limit the connection time.

Comment: It works for android and on another iOS app (Zello) @Larme

Comment: @mag_zbc Yes, calling it `[self.centralManager connectPeripheral:self.pendingDevice.perhipheral options:nil];`, and successfully connecting. The issue is disconnection after ~30 seconds

Comment: The delegate method `didDisconnectPeripheral` should be called. Does it return an error?

Comment: @mag_zbc Yes - i'm getting The specified device has disconnected from us. (error code 7)